# Color Palette reordering increasing order

Tags: python, sorting, colors, transition

Hello community i have rgb nparray of 256 * 3 i want to sort colors just like transition between different colors (i.e. all varients of reds should be placed consective then for next color all varients of that color should be placed consective like HSV model has smooth transition between colors) but first color should have low luminance value because it is responsible to create an index grayscale image.

I think its human visual perception of reordering colors. i have tested various code for the problem but could not be able to find solution for it. Code below is attached for reference which does not work for my case

```
rgb = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(256, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
def color_difference(color1, color2):

  return deltaE_ciede2000(color1, color2, kL=2, kC=2, kH=2)

# Convert RGB to CAM02
cam02 = cspace_convert(rgb, "sRGB1", "JCh")

print("CAM02 values:")
print(cam02)

lightness = cam02[..., 0]  # Extracting lightness values
sorted_indices = np.argsort(lightness)  # Sorting the indices based on lightness

sorted_colors = rgb[sorted_indices]
sorted_cam02 = cam02[sorted_indices]  # Sorting the CAM02 values based on lightness

print("Sorted CAM02 values based on lightness:")
print(sorted_cam02)

sorted_indices = []
unsorted_indices = list(range(len(sorted_cam02)))

max_luminance_index = np.argmin(sorted_cam02[:, 0])
current_index = max_luminance_index
sorted_indices.append(current_index)
unsorted_indices.remove(current_index)


while unsorted_indices:
 current_color = sorted_cam02[current_index]
 min_diff = float('inf')
 closest_index = -1

 for index in unsorted_indices:
    diff = color_difference(current_color, sorted_cam02[index])
    if diff < min_diff:
        min_diff = diff
        closest_index = index

 sorted_indices.append(closest_index)
 unsorted_indices.remove(closest_index)
 current_index = closest_index

sorted_colors = sorted_colors[sorted_indices]
print(sorted_colors)
```

Here is the attached reference diagram. Note that the following diagram is only for letting you understand clearly about problem i dont want to perform interpolation to add extra color.

[Image Attached Showing transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwDlX.png)

I dont have perfect colors available to show like attached diagram. i have colors like diagram attached below. i want to perform task on following color palette

[Actual color palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxWcp.png)